# send serial data from each view in a multiple view app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, serial-port

I've got a multiple view (controller) app for motor control.

The main page selects the function (which motors)  then goes to another page(viewcontroller) to move those associated motors 
(plus range ,minus range and stop on each viewcontroller plus emergency stop).

Using the redpark serial cable for initial versions (ble later on).
I have the main view controller sending serial data but can't get the other view controllers sending data.

Whats the best way to do it ?

I've tried making each view controller a delegate for redparks rscMgrbut it doesn't work
(unless I'm doing something really dumb which is possible)

eg

```
inviewcontrollerx.h

#import "RscMgr.h"

#define BUFFER_LEN 1024


@interface FBInfoViewController : UIViewController <RscMgrDelegate> {
    RscMgr *rscMgr;
    UInt8 rxBuffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    UInt8 txBuffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    BOOL cableConnected;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) RscMgr *rscMgr;

@end


them in each one viewcontrollerx.m
- (void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
rscMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];
[rscMgr ssetDelegate:self];

//etc

}



- (BOOL) sendMessage:(NSString *)Tmessage {

    NSLog(@"sendMSG: ");
    NSLog(@"String: %@", Tmessage);

    int bytesToWrite = Tmessage.length;

    for (int i =0;i < bytesToWrite; i++ ) {
    self->txBuffer[i] = (int)[Tmessage characterAtIndex:i];
    }

    NSLog(@"BYTES WRITTEN = %d", Tmessage.length);
    NSLog(@"Msg = %@", Tmessage);    

    int bytesWritten = [self->rscMgr write:txBuffer length:bytesToWrite];
    NSLog(@"Wrote %d bytes to serial cable.", bytesWritten);

    if (bytesWritten == bytesToWrite)
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
}


then send a message by 
[self sendMSG : @"<VC20c203l,888c99>\n\r"];
```

Only the main(inital view controller) sends serial data.
I need the separate "pages" so the user can adjust one setting/position at a time.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong, but it might be because the rscMgr can only have one delegate at a time. You might try setting the delegate to nil in the main view controller before moving to another controller, and setting that one as the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you rearchitect and use a separate object to control he motor and serial connection. Make it a singleton and all other objects can easily find and communicate with it. If those apps need to get notified when some events happen, have it send out notifications. This is classic style.

Comment: Thank you. Would you suggest making it as an ultility class or making the app delegate the serial delgate and using it to talk to the serial. I've only done fairly simple apps before.

Comment: Hah - you'll find strong opinions on this. I've often created categories on my App delegate, to do things like this. I make a separate .h and .m file, the .h file gets included at the bottom of AppDelegate.h, and thus I can at least keep the methods separate to avoid code bloat. That said, others will shriek at this - that the right was is to provide another separate class etc. Its really up to  you. Note that you can put your app delegate's interface file, or any other singletons, in the pch file and thus be able to access it from any app class without having to import it first. Good luck!